# How do I find records in a mongodb collection based on the results of a find call to a different collection?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have the following collections:

`RideOffers`: a collection of ride offers that users post on the site, and
`BidsOnOffers`: a collection of bids on the above ride offers. Each bid is associated with exactly one ride offer

I would like to send to the user a list of bids on ride offers that she has posted, but not all bids for all ride offers: the user should be able to see only the bids for her rider offers, and not any bids for other people's ride offers. Any ideas on how do I can do this? Here is what I have come up with so far:

```
Meteor.publish('RideOffers', function() { 
    return RideOffers.find();
});

Meteor.publish('BidsOnMyOffers', function() { 
    var MyRideOffers = RideOffers.find({userId: this.userId, active: true});
    return BidsOnOffers.find({ offerId: {$in : [MyRideOffers._id]}, active: true});
});
```

This obviously doesn't work, the problematic part being `{$in : [MyRideOffers._id]}`, I suppose. Do I try to get an array of _id values from `MyRideOffers`? Or is my approach completely wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is right but your syntax is wrong.

To build an array of ids from your RideOffers collection, use fetch (from Meteor cursors) to obtain an array of documents and the "fields" option to select only the _id property from those documents :

```
var myRideOffersIds=RideOffers.find({
    userId:this.userId,
    active:true
},{
    fields:{
        _id:1
    }
}).fetch();
```

Then you can use this variable with $in :

```
return BidsOnOffers.find({
    offerId:{
        $in:myRideOffersIds
    },
    active:true
});
```

Comment: To be even more efficient, use `{fields: {_id: 1}}` as the second argument and you won't even have to `pluck`.

Comment: Didn't think about this option which is way better, so I edited my answer, nice =)

Comment: Actually, the un-edited version of this answer worked for me (the one that uses `_.pluck`. I couldn't get this one to work (maybe I just missed something simple).

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer suggests using fetch() with the "fields" option to build an array of ids from your RideOffers collection, like this:

```
var myRideOffersIds=RideOffers.find({
    userId:this.userId,
    active:true
},{
    fields:{
        _id:1
    }
}).fetch();
```

and then using this variable with $in:

```
return BidsOnOffers.find({
    offerId:{
        $in:myRideOffersIds
    },
    active:true
});
```

However this didn't work for me - no documents were returned. I think it fails because fetch() returns an array of objects: each object only has one field, but it is still an object so the array is something like: [{id:"1233"}, {id:"5678"}]. But the "$in" operator can only search an array of values in the form ["1234", "5678"].

I got this to work using [map](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/reference/method/cursor.map/) to create myRideOffersIds as a simple array of values:

```
var myRideOffersIds=RideOffers.find({
    userId:this.userId,
    active:true
}).map(function(val) {return val._id});
```

Comment: Your answer is hard to follow. Please rewrite it to make it clearer for the questioner. Thank you.